# Unable to verify account name or password despite using correct details

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, accounts

I've had this problem for a while, but I hate not knowing or getting to the bottom of things, so here I am! :)

On an iMac I am running El Capitan 10.11.6 and in the Mail app I successfully send and receive emails from five separate accounts. So all seems good.

However, if I go to System Preferences > Internet Accounts and manually select each of these five accounts, for two of them I get the following *Can't connect to the account* error message:

[image]

Now, when I enter my password, I get the *Unable to verify account name or password* prompt in red text:

[image]

I manage my own domain and email accounts, so know for a fact I have the correct passwords. And, as I said, I am using these accounts fine within Mail. I also use them fine on various iPhones and iPads and other Macs.

Any suggestions as to what's going on?

Comment: Try prefs>Accounts>Advanced & see if 'Automatically detect & maintain...' is enabled. I've known that to change the port & SSL settings below.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for the suggestion. Did you mean System Preferences > Internet Accounts > Advanced ? If so, I don't get the _Automatically detect & maintain..._ option.

Comment: Mail prefs, sorry - it's set individually for each account

Comment: There are actually 2 places, one for incoming, one for outgoing [sorry, I'd forgotten, been a while since I did it] The other is in Outgoing SMTP > edit > advanced.

Comment: Ah, found it. The _Automatically detect & maintain..._ option is enabled. So are you suggesting I should I uncheck the box?

Comment: I've found it to be far more stable since I disabled mine. It was randomly picking new SSL ports for me... which didn't work

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It didn't solve this issue, but I'll keep that option off for a while to see what happens over time.

Comment: I also noticed that if you try to (re)set the password in the Preferences->Accounts Server Settings tab for the account an error like "Unable to store credential due to error -25308 Requested By: Mail" will appear.

Comment: The worst thing is that I can see from the logs on the server that the IMAP login succeeds just fine -- both for Mail, and for accountsd.

Comment: For me the issue was that I was copy-pasting the password and for some reason Apple's Internet Account system preferences do not like that and it was complaining that `unable verify account`

Comment: @MaksimLuzik Yes, many systems or processes don't allow the copying and pasting of passwords as it's not considered best practice. Basically it's seen as increasing the risk of a privacy violation. That said, thanks for coming back to share what the problem was in your case! I'm sure it'll help others! :)

Answer (score 11):

I was having this issue also, tried restarting the computer, editing the SMTP, nothing worked. I went into internet accounts and clicked the remove button (-) in the bottom left. After removing and re-adding the account everything seems to be working fine!

Comment: Since I don't have enough reputation, I put it here in the comments.
This happened to me after I changed my password. I solved this by going to:
Mail -> Preferences -> Accounts -> Server Settings and then in the Password field changing it to the new password. Mails finally started coming in again ;)

Comment: If you're having this issue for Calendar (as I was), then following @SandervandenOord's instructions will solve the same problem.

Answer (score 6):

This is a frustrating bug! Here's what worked for me, though I don't know which of these things ended up doing the trick (Mac OS 10.12.6, Mail 10.3):

1. Open Mail preferences and on the accounts tab paste the new password into the Server Settings tab.
2. Disable the account on the Account Information tab.
3. Restart the whole computer. (probably not necessary)
4. Launch mail, open up preferences again to the accounts tab (this time it showed a green "Online" status).
5. Re-enable the account on the account information tab.
6. At this point, for some reason Mail thinks the account is offline, though I never set it to offline. Click the get mail button and it will ask if you want to bring the account online, click bring all accounts online.

And finally after all that it started working again. This is so ridiculous. Whoever thought you would have to reboot your entire Mac just to update your email password.

Comment: Yes, since macOS 10.12.6. I am experiencing the exact same bug. It happened to me twice. I don’t recommend pasting the password to the System Preferences > Internet Accounts settings.

Comment: This worked for me, although it was enough to disable the account, change the password, then re-enable it without also restarting.

Comment: @Defragged Thanks, I made a note in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, The solution is to delete the entry for the account password in Keychain Access.

the name for the account is:

com.apple.account.Exchange.password

there seems to be a bug as this account doesn't show till you search for a string that matches in this account, like "Exchange"

I got the hint for this solution from this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/246090/297433)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved, for me at least.

Stop everything, entirely remove `~/Library/Keychains/U-U-I-D/`, and reboot.

More details:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/325124/185723

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and also solved it by changing the app password in Keychain Access!
Keychain Access had an old password stored there.

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do, is in the Settings -> Internet Accounts window. Fill in the password in the empty password field.

Now, hit "tab". And then enter.