# Apple Mail won't login after Migration Assistant transfer

Tags: time-machine, mail.app, email, migration, migration-assistant

I recently used Migration Assistant to bring data to a new Mac Mini from a Time Machine backup on my old Mac. After finishing, I am unable to connect to my mail account as it gives the error "unable to verify account name or password". I know for a fact that my password and account are correct, because I can still log into that mail account on my old machine using those credentials.

I have tried:

- restarting
- deleting the existing mail account and trying to add the account back
- Removing keychains related to mail from my keychain access under 'login'

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: who is the account with ? Gmail ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 It is the mail account run by my company. So the host name is mail.companyName.com. When trying to add the account, I am choosing the "Add Other Account" option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution after searching around and trying things.

The answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/325124) led me to the solution. What worked for me from that post was deleting the folders in ~/Library/Keychains that had super long names of numbers and letters. Then I restarted the computer and tried to log in to mail and everything worked.